# expandtab in Vim - specifically in Python files

Tags: python, vim

I've stripped my config out completely, and I'm left with the following bare-bones `~/.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

If I open a python file, then check the `expandtab` setting, I'll see that it's inherited the correct settings (I think from `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/python.vim:49`):

```
setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 tabstop=8
```

---

The problem is when I open multiple files on the command line (e.g: `vim a.py b.py`), or when I open multiple windows from within `vim`.

Below are some steps I've taken to experiment, along with the corresponding results from `:set expandtab?`.

- `vim a.py b.py`

  - One buffer is displayed containing `a.py` with `expandtab`
  - `C-w v` - vertical split, both buffers have `a.py` and `expandtab`
  - `:n`- the buffer now containing `b.py` has `noexpandtab`, the other remains with `expandtab`
- `vim a.py`

  - One buffer is displayed  containing `a.py` with `expandtab`
  - `C-w v` - vertical split, both buffers have `a.py` and `expandtab`
  - `:e b.py` - the buffer that has just loaded `b.py` has `noexpandtab`, the other remains with `expandtab`
- `vim`

  - One empty buffer, with `noexpandtab`
  - `:e a.py` - loaded `a.py`, with `expandtab`
  - `:e b.py` - loaded `b.py`, with `noexpandtab`
- `vim z.txt a.py b.py`

  - One buffer is displayed  containing `z.txt` with `noexpandtab`
  - `:n`- loaded `a.py` has `expandtab`
  - `:n`- loaded `b.py` has `noexpandtab`

Can anyone make sense of this? Or even reproduce it?

As the last two experiments show, it's not simply the act of leaving the initial buffer that causes this... the first file with `filetype=python` behaves, the others do not.

---

Below is the output of `vim --version`, I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 LTS.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:43:18)
Included patches: 1-52
Extra patches: 8.0.0056
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   -perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            -ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl    -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

Comment: What version of Vim is this? I can't reproduce the first case in Vim 8.0.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either. Could you add the full output of `$ vim --version` to your question?

Comment: Thanks, see above.

Comment: I tried to replicate this in `7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Apr  4 2017 18:14:54)` on macOS, but in the first case, they were all `expandtab` - still haven't managed to replicate...

Comment: Damn, thanks @Dan - I'm running on Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 LTS

Comment: I can reproduce it on Ubuntu 14.04.5 but I can't explain the reason...

Comment: Good to know, thanks @Dan ... interesting it worked on your v7.4 on OSX - would you mind perhaps archiving off your `$VIM` directory and sharing it (e.g: `/usr/share/vim`). I'd be interested to compare Ubuntu 14.04 vs OSX.

Comment: Sure, I put a zip of it at https://www.dropbox.com/s/faro2wftn8y6ufe/vim.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thanks @Dan, will investigate... there are plenty of changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to a bug in the `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/python.vim` that is packaged in Ubuntu 14.04.5 (and possibly other versions).

To rectify, I have applied the following patch:
[see pastebin](https://pastebin.com/RyVB9mJH) (SO doesn't play nice with tabs)

```sh
curl https://pastebin.com/raw/RyVB9mJH | sudo patch -d /usr/share/vim/vim74 -p1
```

---

I'd like to thank @DanLowe for:

1. Confirming that he could reproduce this, and
2. Providing his `/usr/share/vim` files from an OSX install for me to review

---

Explanation:

Ubuntu's packaged `ftplugin/python.vim` has the following line:

```
if exists('*<SID>Python_jump') | finish | endif
```

This will check for the existence of a script-local function called `Python_jump` - if it exists it will bail out.

Later in the file we find useful configuration, in particular:

```
setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 tabstop=8
```

This fully explains why the first Python file has `expandtab`, while all the others have `noexpandtab`.

In contrast, the OSX version of `ftplugin/python.vim` that Dan provided encompasses the script-local `Python_jump` declaration in a test for its existence, simply skipping it if it's already defined, and continuing with the remaining settings.

```
if !exists('*<SID>Python_jump')
  fun! <SID>Python_jump(motion) range
      let cnt = v:count1
      let save = @/    " save last search pattern
      mark '
      while cnt > 0
          silent! exe a:motion
          let cnt = cnt - 1
      endwhile
      call histdel('/', -1)
      let @/ = save    " restore last search pattern
  endfun
endif
```

---

This brute-force effort was made more tricky by the following line found in `vim74/debian.vim`:

```
set runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
```

Yep, that's right... the `VIM` environment variable you might be setting is forcibly overwritten. Yay \o/